# Chrome navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() error 403

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, navigator, google-geolocation

For some reason suddenly when calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` I get this error:

`Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403.`

It used to work perfectly yesterday! Could there be anything with their servers??

Comment: I am experiencing the same problems in Chrome and Firefox but seems to work find in IE. Tried it on a colleague machine and getting the same results.

Comment: Happens for me too. I suspect that google changed somthing in their geo location policy over non secure http

Comment: Same problem here. Everything ok yesterday Aug 31 2015.

Comment: thank god it is not just me

Comment: Same probleme here...chrome error 403...safari tiemout expired http://jsfiddle.net/mhj82/38/

Comment: possible duplicate of [In new chrome (44.0.2403.157) geolocations doesnt works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328133/in-new-chrome-44-0-2403-157-geolocations-doesnt-works)

Comment: Looks like it was solved at googleapis.com

Comment: The problem occurs again, Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears it is back up now. But before I realized it was working, I used another way to get location data as recommended by another user on reddit.com

```
var latLong;
$.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io", function(ipinfo){
    console.log("Found location ["+ipinfo.loc+"] by ipinfo.io");
    latLong = ipinfo.loc.split(",");
});
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3j8ipj/anyone_else_had_issues_with_the_html5_geolocation/

Comment: This appears to be unreliable, I'm showing up in richardson texas, which is news to me, since I'm in SF. Sorry for being snarky.

Comment: This just looks up the current IP in big geoIP tables - specially on mobile devices this is not the best way (GSM IP's are Pool-IPs, and GPS is much more accurate)

Answer (score 1):

This happens for me too on [idoco.github.io/map-chat](http://idoco.github.io/map-chat)

I suspect that this is related the the changes google planed for [Deprecating Powerful Features on Insecure Origins](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) it seems that some changes were done in the last few days in this chromium [Issue 520765: Deprecation and removal of powerful features on insecure origins](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=520765)

Can you test your site over https to confirm that?

In the meanwhile I found this api usage as a workaround on [this repo](https://github.com/HammerIO/map-chat/commit/e7455457d2b5aac871c89a2387e9a845871cda06):

```
  $.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io", function(doc){
    var latlong = doc.loc.split(",")
    setUserLocation(parseFloat(latlong[0]), parseFloat(latlong[1]));
    getLocation(parseFloat(latlong[0]), parseFloat(latlong[1])).then(function(res){
      userLocationName = res
    })
    initialiseEventBus();
    map.panTo(userLocation);

  }, function(err) {
    setUserLocation(Math.random()*50, Math.random()*60);
    userLocationName = "unknown.na"
    initialiseEventBus();
    map.panTo(userLocation);
  })
```

Comment: localhost is defined as secure here: [Prefer Secure Origins For Powerful New Features](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features) but still doesn't work too...

Comment: Tried both Http:// and Https:// on internal and external sites with no change in results (Fails in Chrome/FF works in IE. Tried it in fiddler with a standard http:// head and it worked.

Comment: we’re using https and this still happens

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you have to check your [developer dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com) and make sure that your API key has no usage restrictions or warnings.