# Chrome Javascript Console Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor

I am working on a meteor.js app and I am using `Session.set` and `Session.get` to pass data along. Now last night my app was working just fine but this morning none of it seems to be working. And whenever i try to get a session from the chrome console it just prints out whatever I typed with out giving any messages or any data.

Ex:
`Session.get("min-distance-query");`

just prints out: `Session.get("min-distance-query");`

I also have functions to get my lon/lat coords `Geolocation.latLng();` which was working as well before I went to bed and this morning it is also not working.

And again it does the same thing in the console when I try to run the function in there. It just prints out `Geolocation.latLng();` where it used to print out an object with a lng/lat value in it.

Has any one experienced this before?

Comment: try typing `javascript:console.log(Session.get("min-distance-query"));` on your browser address bar, and check what console shows.

Comment: Just tried it and it again just prints out "javascript:console.log(Session.get("min-distance-query"));" no errors or anything else

Comment: No, I mean to add the line in the address bar, not in the console.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean by adding it in the address bar. like after my localhost:3000?

Comment: Replace the entire address with `javascript:console.log(Session.get("min-distance-query"));` and press enter.

Comment: Okay I see, that was able to print out the value of the session into the console. But my other function Gelocaton.latLng(); still not longer works as it did last. And whenever I print it out to the function it just says null

Comment: Not so quick. Check another console, like Firefox's. Is everything working in Firefox ?

Comment: So in the firefox console everything is working as it should. The Geolocation function grabs my long/lat and all the Session.get commands work. In firefox the app is totally functional as I left it last night and in chrome is still not working. Very weird.

Comment: Try same app in another machine's Chrome. If that works, I think you will be better by reinstalling Chrome.

Comment: I do not have access to another device atm but I have just re installed chrome and the console is working again as in it will print out my session so that is good, but for some reason chrome will not grab my location while firebox will

Comment: It should be a permission setting. But you can post a new question =)

Comment: I will play around with it and see if I can figure it out. I have find some people posting on google chronium experiencing the same issue I currently am. If I can not get any luck solving it I will post a new Q. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Niloct I have been able to get the console to function as expected.

As he mentioned in the comments I just had to reinstall chrome and it began working again.

NOTE: the Gelocation.lngLat(); function is apparently not working because of an unrelated issue regarding chrome. A stack overflow post about this issue can be found here: [Chrome navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329464/chrome-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-error-403)

Hopefully it will get resolved soon.