# Getting error when trying to get getlocation in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

I'm trying to get the geocordinates and I've tried my best.
I looked up similar questions on stackoverflow, ionic forums etc. But none of them has a solution. Please help!!

Here is the Code:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(res => {
     console.log(res.coords);
}).catch((error) => {
     console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

Error

> PositionError {code: 2, message: "Network location provider at
>   'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403."}
>       code
>       :
>       2
>       message
>       :
>       "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403."
>       **proto**
>       :
>       PositionError

Comment: try to run this in your google chrome's console  -navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()

Comment: returns undefined

Comment: try in different browser...we have to check whether this issue is from google or from our side?

Comment: sorry..try this >  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data){ console.log(data);  });

Comment: I tried a bit of code from MDN and this is what I got. What might be the issue?
Please see the result 
http://imgur.com/sDXfRGv

Comment: @AnkushJain same. getting undefine across all browsers.!

Comment: try updating our chrome browser

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179686

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149671/discussion-between-j-snow-and-ankush-jain).

Comment: I found almost the same question and answer. Check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329464/chrome-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-error-403